# Setting up Branching Priority for GUROBI in Pyomo

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, pyomo

I am currently experimenting with GUROBI and would appreciate some kind advice on the following:

In [Pyomo: Setting variable branching priorities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887602/pyomo-setting-variable-branching-priorities), there was a response to doing so for CPLEX, hence I would like to ask if anyone has managed to do so for GUROBI too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @Richard's answer, you can simply change any of Gurobi's attributes from your Pyomo code as follow:

```
msolver = SolverFactory('gurobi')
msolver.options['TimeLimit'] = 100
msolver.options['BranchPriority'] = 0
```

You can set the `BranchPriority` to whatever value you decided.

Comment: Thanks Oguz. However, I need to use the branching priority functionality the way it is used in the link above.

Comment: Hi @Mike, if you look at these links:(https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/1299 and https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/pull/1300) it seems that this enhancement of pyomo has been developed for cplex only (as a starting point). I could not find any document about Gurobi. See also https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/1587.

Answer (score 3):

You can control the branching priorities in Gurobi using the [BranchPriority](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/branchpriority.html) attribute, which you can then store in an [.ord](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/ord_format.html) file.

This file can then be provided as an input using the [InputFile](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/inputfile.html) parameter.

If you cannot add a parameter through the pyomo API, you can always create a [gurobi.env](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/quickstart_linux/using_a_grb_env_file.html) file in the directory where your script is located and store all your parameter modifications there.

**Edit**:

The `InputFile` parameter cannot be added as a parameter in the `gurobi.env`. Instead, you should follow @Oguz's approach:

```
msolver.options['InputFile'] = '<path-to-ord-file>'
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. Could you help me by providing an example of the code on the file and the associated workflow for invoking it as it seems to be a protracted process? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, it seems that InputFile is only meant for use in command-line, I tried using it in the gurobi.env and an error message was returned stating that it was unrecognized.

Comment: Also, I have look up the bin directory of the latest version, it does not contain the sample gurobi.env file

Comment: He, that's interesting: there are some parameters which you can only set on the model level, not on the environment level, and this is one of them. Your best bet at this point is probably what Oguz wrote:

```
msolver.options['InputFile'] = '<path-to-file>'
```

Sorry for the confusion, I should have known better (I work for Gurobi)

Comment: Unfortunately, those are only meant for Cplex, I have tried them to no avail.

Comment: Could you help me by pasting the syntax of the sample gurobi.env file so that I can experiment with it?

Comment: Though I am still hoping pyomo can do rhe same for gurobi as that of cplex. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, according to our Support page it should work what I wrote:

https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360074274611-Set-params-NonConvex-2-with-Pyomo

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working

Comment: Pyomo returns - No parameters matching 'InputFile' found

Comment: This is really weird. Would you mind raising a support ticket on support.gurobi.com and mentioning my name? Then I'll have a look there.

Comment: I did so around the time when I first solicited your advice. Till now there has been no response

Comment: Though I did explicitly seek out anyone for help.

Comment: Typo, Though I did not explicitly seek out anyone for help

Comment: Could you please submit the request again with my name in it? Thanks

Comment: The URL of the new request is https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4402982080785-Setting-up-Branching-Priority-for-GUROBI-in-Pyomo-Attention-RIchard-from-OR-Stackexchange-